# change LinearGradient colors ratio dynamically for custom seekBar

Tags: java, android, material-design, android-seekbar, android-graphics

I have created a seekbar with a custom `LinearGradient` drawable. However, I want to be able to change gradient ratio for each color, here I use 3 colors, they get equally distributed if `positions` is `null`. What I want, in fact, is to provide width or ratio to each color, for example change red ratio and set it only form **0% to 10%** of `seekBar` `width`.

Here i want to, set 0% to 10% red, 10% - 80% yellow, and 80% to 100% red, and be able to change the width values for each color dynamically.

Is this possible, and if yes, can anyone guide me on how?

**My code**

```
private ShapeDrawable getSeekBarGradientDrawable(int mRectWidth, int mRectHeight) {
    int[] colors = new int[] { Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, getResources().getColor(R.color.primaryButton, null)};

DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
int width = displayMetrics.widthPixels - (int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.margin_padding_size_medium);

    Shader shader = new LinearGradient(
            0,
            0,
            width,
            mRectHeight,
            colors, new float[] {0.1f,0.7f,0.2f},
            Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

    ShapeDrawable shape = new ShapeDrawable(new RectShape());
    shape.getPaint().setShader(shader);
    return shape;
}
```

Image can be seen from current settings, its not as i described.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer applies to using a *LinearGradient* as a *Shader*.

Change the *LinearGradient* colors to transition from a color to the same color by setting the `colors` array as follows:

```
int[] colors = new int[]{Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.GREEN};
```

Change the *LinearGradient* to define the regions for the colors as follows: See [LinearGradient with positions](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/LinearGradient#LinearGradient(float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20long%5B%5D,%20float%5B%5D,%20android.graphics.Shader.TileMode))

```
Shader shader = new LinearGradient(  
    0,  
    0,  
    width,  
    mRectHeight,  
    colors, new float[]{0f, 0.1f, 0.1f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f},  
    Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
```

This forces the *Shader* to transition from a color to the same color over a region creating a solid color.

[image]

The above will give an instant transition from one color to another. If you want a narrow transition (narrower than the default for *LinearGradient*), you can manipulate the colors and positions arrays as follows. In the following, we change the transition from the red to yellow.

```
int[] colors = new int[]{Color.RED, Color.RED, Color.YELLOW, Color.YELLOW, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.GREEN};
Shader shader = new LinearGradient(
        0,
        0,
        width,
        mRectHeight,
        colors, new float[]{0f, 0.1f, 0.15f, 0.15f, 0.8f, 0.8f, 1.0f},
        Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
```

[image]

Comment: thank you @Cheticamp, i appreciate your help on this. I need to support api level less than 29. By custom drawable are you referring to xml drawables? I look into that also not sure if i will be able to update it dynamically. I will look in detail. thanks

Comment: yes i just checked in api level 28, it is working. one thing though, colors not blending in current version. Looking into to enable smooth mixing of color at edges and i will accept your answer. Thank you :)

Comment: @AmirDora.I don't understand your last comment. Are you saying that you do not want an instant transition from one color to another but want to have a narrow transition?

Comment: yes exactly @Cheticamp, and sadly i am not able to find any documentation on it.