# Change TextView background based on width percentage

Tags: android, background, textview, background-color, android-progressbar

I've got a simple TextView with a lightgreen background:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@color/lightgreen"
/>
```

Basically I am using this TextView as a custom "overview/progressbar".
Thus, I want to change the background in the different colors.

For example:

0%-25% of width = light green color

25%-66%  of width = yellow color

66%-100% of width = red color

So instead looking like this:

[image]
It should look like this:

[image]

Is there any good solution doing this?

I've tried using different Segment ProgressBar libraries, however none of them had the option to set the percentage times of the color "dividers"

Comment: Does text view contain text? Or is it just a background color?

Comment: @Amjad its just a background color

Comment: Can you use LinearLayout with weights for 4 children? It would be faster. You could also use xml to declare three shape colors.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64444959/6287910) will help from a previous answer of mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using the [ClipDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable).
Create a layer-list ([LayerDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable)) with the list of progress layers like:

progress_bg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <clip android:drawable="@color/red" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <clip android:drawable="@color/yellow" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <clip android:drawable="@color/green" />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and use it as the background of a TextView.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/progress_text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/progress_bg" />
```

To apply progress values:

```
private static final int MAX_LEVEL = 10_000;
private static final float[] LEVELS_PCT = new float[]{.25f, .66f, 1f};
//
final LayerDrawable progressBg = (LayerDrawable) progressTextView.getBackground();
for (int index = 0, count = LEVELS_PCT.length; index < count; index++) {
    progressBg.getDrawable(count - 1 - index)
            .setLevel((int) (MAX_LEVEL * LEVELS_PCT[index]));
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
//Get the percentage ProgressBar and then apply the command to the text
float x = LoadingProgress.getProgress() ;
        

if (x > 0.2 && x < 0.6){
                MyTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorGreen));
            }
            else if (x > 0.7)
            {
                MyTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorYellow));
            } else {
                MyTextView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorRed));
            }
```

Hope this solution helps you

Comment: 1)That changes the textcolor, not the background color. And 2) it only shows one color at a time and not three

Comment: Do you want to change only the background color of the progress bar and the splitting of colors?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16893209/how-to-customize-a-progress-bar-in-android?rq=1

Comment: Here are some answers for how to create a custom progress bar, you can control the programming file a little bit to get the desired result